# Как ускорить работу кода на C#

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как можно ускорить работу данного кода? Требуется, чтобы скорость обработки кода не превышала 1sec.

Задание кратко:

> Есть строка ABCD и CDB. Выделяешь из каждой строки пары (AB BC CD и CD DB) и ищешь количество одинаковых.

На данный момент скорость работы составляет 1.09sec.
Немного поправил код (сделал через List), выдало на последнем тесте 1.08. Не могу придумать ускорить поиск.

```
string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
string str2 = Console.ReadLine();

List<string> pairs1 = new List<string>();
List<string> pairs2 = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length - 1; i++)
    pairs1.Add(str1[i].ToString() + str1[i + 1]);
for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length - 1; i++)
    pairs2.Add(str2[i].ToString() + str2[i + 1]);

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pairs1.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < pairs2.Count(); j++)
    {
        if (pairs1[i] == pairs2[j])
        {
            count++;

            break;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Вот, решил

```
        string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string str2 = Console.ReadLine();
        long test123 = 0;
        long[,] kek = new long[26, 26];
        for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            kek[Convert.ToInt64(str1[i]) - 65, Convert.ToInt64(str1[i + 1])- 
            65]++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            test123 = test123 + kek[Convert.ToInt64(str2[i]) - 65, 
            Convert.ToInt64(str2[i + 1]) - 65];
            kek[Convert.ToInt64(str2[i]) - 65, Convert.ToInt64(str2[i + 1]) 
        - 65] = 0;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(test123);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61633/discussion-on-question-by--------c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что получилось

```
string str1 = Console.ReadLine();
string str2 = Console.ReadLine();
long test123 = 0;
long[,] kek = new long[26, 26];
for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length - 1; i++)
{
    kek[Convert.ToInt64(str1[i]) - 65, Convert.ToInt64(str1[i + 1])- 
    65]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < str2.Length - 1; i++)
{
    test123 = test123 + kek[Convert.ToInt64(str2[i]) - 65, 
    Convert.ToInt64(str2[i + 1]) - 65];
    kek[Convert.ToInt64(str2[i]) - 65, Convert.ToInt64(str2[i + 1]) 
    - 65] = 0;
}
Console.WriteLine(test123);
```

Comment: Можете отметить свой ответ как верный (галочка слева от ответа).